# find an integer in a double map container

Tags: c++, dictionary

I wanted to know if there was a way to find an int in a double type map container. For instance in the following example

```
std::map<double,double> mt;
mt[2.33] =3.45;

if(mt.find(2)!=mt.end()) //How to do a search for an int instead of a map
{
    //Found
}
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to tell the map to search for an int instead of a double. Since the map would search for a double by default.

Comment: This is a map with a `double` key. You can search for `double`s in it. How is the map supposed to know what you want if you search for something else? Is it supposed to round? What if I do `mt.find("square root of 2")` - is it supposed to parse and calculate that and give me the key closest to that value?

Comment: This question is totally unclear. What are you trying to find? Clearly there's no element "2" in your map.

Comment: That was a question and i wanted to know that may be there was a standard algorithm that might help.

Comment: @KerrekSB just updated the question

Comment: @KerrekSB I think may be OP is looking for integral closest match

Comment: The question still makes no sense. *What do you expect to find?*

Comment: I expect it to find the no 2 and go inside the condition statement since it has the key 2.33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is to use `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` member functions to get a range of values around your integer, and then check this range manually.

Other way is to use a map with custom comparator that compares keys as integers (see [std::map referernce](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)), so you preserve initial key values and can search for integers. But you can't search for doubles then.

Anyways, the task is a bit strange, you probably should reconsider your data structures choice for your problem.

Comment: A custom comparator means you cannot even *store* distinct doubles.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
 it = mt.lower_bound(2);
```

However, you need to check the item afterwards;

```
 it->first<3;
```

must yield true for correct result.

Answer (score 1):

if you are interested only in the integral part (or anything else, as you can use a lambda for that), you might use

```
auto result = find_if(begin(mt), end(mt), 
                      [&](pair<double, double> p){return (int)(p.first) == 2)}
                     )
if (result != mt.end())
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

The use case for such a kind of approach still remains unclear...